# GoDaddy domain vs Azure VM Host

Tags: hosting, godaddy

So I'v create a WebPage witch is a basic html/js file. And I want it to be hosted somewhere in this world. So I bought a domain name here on GoDaddy (tiresizecalc.ca) and place my file a Virtual Machine on Azure.

Now I wish to have my domain name, tiresizecalc.ca be fowarded to my host on azure, And I've some difficulties.

I've try some setting, like adding a HostName (app.tiresizecalc.ca => 104.41.135.209) in the GoDaddy DNS management page and also set the fowarding to http://app.tiresizecalc.ca

But now when I type the domain tiresizecalc.ca in a browser, in my case Chrome, the url changes to the IP address of the host http://104.41.135.209/ instead of keeping the domain name.

What should I do to have it keeping the domaine name in the address bar?

[image]

Comment: The question is off-topic in  [webapps.se]. It might be on-topic in [webmasters.se] but it's too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got the solutions.

I've added a "Record" of type "A" in the DNS Management page, and it seam to work so far.
[image]